# Spring Batch @JobScope bean creation error "A bean with that name has already been defined"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

In my Spring batch project (Spring Boot version 2.3.4.RELEASE, Java 1.8), I have a processor component that needs to access the Job Id (for tracking purpose). I added @JobScope to the bean declaration and this allows me to access the Job Id.

```
@Component("dealerItemProcessor")
@JobScope
public class DealerItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Dealer, Dealer> {    
   @Value("#{jobExecution}")
   private JobExecution jobExecution;
    
   @Override
   public Dealer process(final Dealer dealer) throws Exception {
      //Get jobExecution.getJobId(), process data bean
   }
```

I declared the Job in XML like this:

```
<job id="syncJob" >
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="itemReader"
                   processor="dealerItemProcessor"
                   writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="1"/>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
    <listeners>
        <listener ref="syncJobCompletionNotificationListener"/>
    </listeners>
</job>
```

The XML configuration is loaded as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath:batch-job.xml")
public class XMLConfigurationLoader {
}
```

The Job is scheduled like this:

```
public SyncJobScheduler(@Qualifier("syncJob") Job dealerSyncJob,
                              JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    this.syncJob = syncJob;
    this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
}
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */1 * * *")
public void schedule() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
   jobLauncher.run(syncJob, new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addDate("date", new Date())
                .toJobParameters());
}
```

When I build and run the project in a Linux OS server and OpenJDK 1.8, I get the following error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'scopedTarget.dealerItemProcessor', defined in BeanDefinition defined in URL [jar:file:/var/www/jobs/upload-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/sync/connect/processor/DealerItemProcessor.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in URL [jar:file:/var/www/jobs/upload-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/sync/connect/processor/DealerItemProcessor.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

I have enabled debug mode and see the same error. How can I troubleshoot this? Can you please give some pointers?

**Update 1:**
I tried changing JobScope to StepScope, and see a similar exception.
2020-10-15 10:53:02.651 [DEBUG] [main]

```
[org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter:37] Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'scopedTarget.dealerItemProcessor' defined in BeanDefinition defined in URL [jar:file:/var/www/jobs/upload-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/sync/connect/processor/DealerItemProcessor.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in URL [jar:file:/var/www/jobs/upload-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/sync/connect/processor/DealerItemProcessor.class]] for bean 'scopedTarget.dealerItemProcessor': There is already [Generic bean: class [com.sync.connect.processor.DealerItemProcessor]; scope=step; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/var/www/jobs/upload-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/sync/connect/processor/DealerItemProcessor.class]] bound.
```

Comment: Could you please try `@StepScope` instead of `@JobScope`. Could you please let me know why you need @JobScope for this component.

Comment: @SujayMohan With `@JobScope` I get a similar error.

Comment: @SujayMohan I need a unique identifier for the marking/tracking the data processed during each run of the Job.

Comment: I hope you need `@JobScope` to get the jobExecution and getId right?

Comment: SpringBoot is creating two instances of the dealerItemProcessor bean. It creates the first during the component scan, and the second when processing the job lifecycle beans. The default behavior is to throw an error when the second bean is created. You can override this behavior by adding `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` to your application.properties. Separately, I was able to get your sample working by replacing `@EnableAutoConfiguration` with `@EnableBatchProcessing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by implementing the StepExecutionListener. This gives access to the StepExecution object, from which we get the Job Id.

```
@Component("dealerItemProcessor")
public class DealerItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Dealer, Dealer> , StepExecutionListener {
    
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public Dealer process(final Dealer dealer) throws Exception {
    //get unique JobId like this - stepExecution.getJobExecutionId()
    // process logic
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        //get the stepExecution Object.
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This solution solves the need to get JobId by providing an alternate. It does not solve the Bean creation exception posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@StepScope` instead of `@JobScope`. You can use `stepExecution.getJobExecution()` to get the jobExecution. Then you as you have mentioned you can get the jobId.